# I'm using Yeoman to generate new angular app. Node modules installed are much more that listed in package.json, is that normal?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, yeoman, package.json

I'm new to using Yeoman, and I noticed that node modules are similar to node modules for other projects as well as the node modules available in the root path for node on my laptop, I don't know if there's something wrong with my setting up or that's normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely normal.
The one present in root are globally installed packages.
While when you run `npm install` the packages get installed in the project directory as per the `package.json` present

Also these packages would be more than what you have in package.json, because it also installs modules which are present as dependency to the the one you have specified in your `package.json`

So if you install yoeman generator which as a dependency chalk,  you would also see a module support-color being installed, because it's a dependency for chalk